# Closing opened resource files?

Tags: java, codenameone

In Codename One, we can load resources by doing something like this:

```
gfx=Resources.open("/gfx.res");
```

What is the best way to close an opened resource file once we're finished using it (AKA, already loaded the images onto the GPU and would like to close the resource to free up CPU)? Thank you!

Comment: There is nothing to close here. You've loaded data into memory, it gets freed the way Java frees memory: automatic garbage collection once nothing has a reference to the resource object.

Comment: So if "gfx" is declared and opened inside "init" in this example, it is automatically closed/freed once the init function/method finishes running? @zapl

Comment: No, it is freed by garbage collection, as @zapl just told you.

Comment: @EJP _When_ is it freed by garbage collection?

Comment: When garbage collection runs, which is basically whenever it likes, but certainly before any `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown. This is rather basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources will get collected by the GC at "some point in the future" if you don't keep a reference to them. So if gfx isn't stored as a pointer in your main class the GC will notice the "garbage" and collect it.